# Changing button images when hovered or activated in CSS 3

Tags: html, css

I have the below buttons set in HTML

```
<input type="image"  id="s_button" src="s_button.png " alt="Submit Form" />
<input type="image"  id="s_b_advanced" src="s_b_advanced.png " alt="Submit Form" />
```

And the following CSS

```
#s_button{
    top: 328px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 970px;
    height: 50px;
}
#s_b_advanced{
    top: 312px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1040px;
    height: 80px;
```

I have other button images that I have created in Illustrator for the hover and active states of the button. How do I change the button image when it is hovered and activated? I don't want to apply a border or anything, I would prefer to use the other images that I have created

Comment: the best choice is using CSS sprite:
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

but also u can use `#s_button:hover` <but not work perfectly>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `<button>` tag instead of using `<input>`, and then modifying the image via the CSS pseudo-element `:before` (or `::before` if you want to [ignore IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#Browser_compatibility)). You'd need something like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="s_button"></button>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#s_button { /*normalize button styles*/
    background:white;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#s_button:before {
    content: url('http://i.imgur.com/JropBNb.png?1');
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
#s_button:hover:before {
    content: url('http://i.imgur.com/fJJtNWc.jpg?1');
}
#s_button:active:before {
    content: url('http://i.imgur.com/KhLxNLo.png?1');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hcr6/)

The `:before` selector will then change depending on if the button is hovered over. The images I used were just some example images from Google, but you can use any valid URL there, of course. You can also modify the other styles on the button and the images.

The first block of styles is to undo the default styles applied to `<button>` elements, while still preserving the form-submitting effects of the button itself.

Answer (score 1):

If a little javascript is ok with you, then you can solve your problem easily by this method[*beginner*]

**JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/RaA66/1/**

**html**

```
<input type="image" id="s_button" src="image1.png" alt="Submit Form"
 onmousedown="clicked(this);" 
 onmouseup="normal(this);" 
 onmouseover="hover(this);" 
 onmouseout="normal(this);" 
/>
```

**js** [put this in `<head><script>..</script></head>` tag.]

```
function clicked(el) {
    el.src = 'onclickimage.png';
}


function normal(el) {
    el.src = 'image1.png';
}


function hover(el) {
    el.src = 'onhoverimage.jpg';
}
```